# PHP: Get name of the class the current function was defined in

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

In PHP I'd like to find out in a function in which class this function was defined in, even if it was inherited by another class.

Let me give you an example:

```
class cParent {
   function getDefinedInClassName() {
      return function_I_am_looking_for();
   }
}

class cChild1 extends cParent {
}

class cChild2 extends cParent {
   function getDefinedInClassName() {
      return parent::getDefinedInClassName();
   }
}

$objParent = new cParent();
$objParent->getDefinedInClassName(); // should return 'cParent'

$objChild1 = new cChild1();
$objChild1->getDefinedInClassName(); // should return 'cParent'

$objChild2 = new cChild2();
$objChild2->getDefinedInClassName(); // should return 'cChild2'
```

**EDIT**:

Just realized I had an error in the code. I have corrected it. Now it shows the actual problem. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: `__CLASS__`, `self::class`, `get_class()` pick any

Comment: Just realized I had an error in the code. I have corrected it. Now it shows the actual problem and Alex's solution does not work anymore. Do you have a solution for this as well, Alex? Many thanks and sorry for the mistake!

Comment: There is no difference between cChild1 and cChild2. cChild2::getDefinedInClassName does exactly the same what cChild1::getDefinedInClassName does.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this simplified example the two functions do exactly the same. But the question is: Is cParent::getDefinedInClassName able to know whether it was called directly via $objParent / $objClient1 or via parent:: and $objChild2?
But I guess a function cannot know how / in which context it was called.

Comment: No, of course not. `parent::` is called in both cases. Explicitly in cChild2 and implicitly in cChild1. Nothing stops you to create `protected function getClassName()` and overwrite it in cChild2.

Comment: Of course, you are right. What I tried to do does not make any sense. Many thanks for clarifying this. I think I've worked for too long today...

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/function.get-class.php I think you should try this function.

```
get_class($this)
```

will return the name of the current class.

Comment: Just realized I had an error in the code. I have corrected it. Now it shows the actual problem. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: Yes, it does, as well as static::class. But if I get it, cChild1 is expected to return name of the parent.